# struts2 + spring4 + mybatis3 if use @Transactional will be a mistake (Autowired(required=true))

Tags: spring

I am using spring `@Transactional` to manage MySQL transactional.
But the way I add `@Transactional` is wrong.

```
@Service
//@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserInfoService extends BaseService

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoAccessor userInfoAccessor;
        //@Transactional
        public void insert()
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("userName", "test");
            userInfoAccessor.insert(map);
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Unable to instantiate Action, com.luotuo.xiaobao.action.IndexAction, defined for 'index' in namespace '/'Error creating bean with name 'com.luotuo.xiaobao.action.IndexAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.luotuo.xiaobao.service.UserInfoService com.luotuo.xiaobao.action.IndexAction.userInfoService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.luotuo.xiaobao.service.UserInfoService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

You can download my project source [here](http://120.26.113.117/fwProject.rar).

What is the correct way to set this up?

Comment: The error you're getting says unable to find a `UserInfoService` to autowire into `IndexAction.userInfoService`, that has probably nothing to do with `@Transactional`.

Comment: if you download my project please please uncomment UserInfoService.java 22 line (//@Transactional) and try again thank you